# How to check if a user upgraded using parse?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, parameters, parse-platform

My app has a login and signup. Once the user is logged in he can then choose to upgrade the account. When the account is upgraded, a new class in parse is created called "Upgrade". Here it has a bunch of subclasses with stored information. Then once the user is upgraded it brings him to a special page that only upgraded users have access to. But how can I check on login if the user is upgraded, and if he is, automatically bring him to the special page.

In my parse, I have the User information stored with subclasses "Username" and "Password". Then in a separate class I have the upgrade information stores with subclasses "Address", "Phone Number", and I have a linker to link back to the user who created it.

my current code for login is:

```
@IBAction func loginButton(sender:AnyObject) {
var username = self.usernameTextField.text
var password = self.passwordTextField.text

if(password.utfCount <5) {
var alert = UIAlertView(title:"Invalid", message: "Password must be greater than 5", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle:"OK")
}
else {
PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(username, password: password, block:{(user, error) -> Void in

if ((user != nil) {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginSegue", sender: nil)
```

This is the basic code but it does not check to see if the user is upgraded.

I tried:

```
if(PFUser.currentUser() == PFQuery(className:"Upgrade")) { 
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("UpgradedSegue")
```

But obivously this didnt work due to the current user not equaling that class.
What kind of code could I user to check if the user made a Upgrade class within parse?

- I have tried messing around with fetchinbackground code and `enter code here`objectinbackground but I can't seem to make those work.

Comment: What does your Upgrade table look like? What is the link between User and Upgrade? Maybe you could store the Upgrade as a Pointer on the User object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the Swift very well, so sorry if there are errors, but try something like:

```
var query = PFQuery(className:"Upgrade")
query.whereKey("user", equalTo:currentUser.objectId)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error != nil
    println("The getFirstObject request failed.")
  } else if object == nil{
    //No Upgrade object with that user's ID
  } else {
    // The find succeeded, user has created an Upgrade object
    println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
  }
}
```

You could also set up your code to store the pointer to the Upgrade object on the user, rather than the other way around. You could set a bool value on the user to see if they have upgraded. If it is true, then take them to the upgrade screen, or fetch the Upgrade object, whatever you need first.

Comment: Thanks for that! It is helping, not working entirely, but it got me thinking. I am now trying to input the username and password into the upgrade class. So that way, it can just check the business class for the user. So I now have upgrade ["Username"] = PFUser.currentUser().username and upgrade ["Password"] = PFUser.currentUser().password. But I am getting an error with this. Specifically thread 1 signal: SIGABRT. But I don't get it when I remove those.

Comment: Update: I found out the error from the comment below is from the password subclass. Because the password is hidden, I cannot save it because it doesn't know what it is saving.

Comment: @JCDOSAJ yeah, you can't access the password, and really shouldn't.  Use Parse's loginInBackgroundWithBlock method, and inside of the block, if there aren't errors, check your user's ["didUpgrade"] boolean.  In obj-c, I have to store that value as a NSNumber, then get the boolValue from the NSNumber. Don't know about swift.  If it's true, go to the Upgrade pages, and if not, go to the normal login.

Comment: Im actually reworking it to make it easier on my part. When, I am having the user create a new password. So that way I can check it all inthe upgrade class. Now the plan is to have a subscription. So there will have to be code later on saying that if the user is not subscribed then make them act like an unupgraded user. But that is later on down the road

Comment: I would be careful about doing it that way.  Are you enforcing that password to be the same in the User class and the Upgrade class? What if it's different and they try to log in with their upgraded password, but parse can't log them in because you are never entering their original parse user password? I'd really recommend something more like storing a pointer to the Upgrade class on your User. You can check to see if it's nil to see if they are upgraded or not, and you'll always have the data right there so you won't need to query for it.

Comment: That's a good point, I was going to have them log in as this new user, and my log in would first check for the upgrade user then the regular user. But this sounds like a better idea, ill see what I can do to come up with it. Any suggestions? I know how to put a pointer into my user class, but it is checking to see if it is upgraded. The intial code on the top didn't work out.

Comment: @JCDOSAJ Like I said, I don't know Swift, so I can't give you exact code, but if you set up the User object to have an Upgrade pointer in the Parse console, you can use whatever the Stripe equivalent of objectForKey: method is to get the pointer, then see if it is == nil.  If it is, the user hasn't upgraded, and if it isn't, you have the Upgrade object that has any relevant information, and you know you can send the user to the Upgraded screen.